# How to recall the observable to fetch data from retrofit wihtout creating a subscriber again

Tags: android, rx-java

My problem is i want to load the data in an activity from server using an observable , when i subscribe to it in onCreate() i automatically get the data from the server and also there is an swipe to refresh when an user swipe , i want same observable to retrieve data from server again,

questions

1) is it a good idea to create an subscription again and again when a user swipes to refresh since there can more than 10 subscription if user swipes 10 times

2) if the above is not a good idea , what to do to make observable fetch data from  server without creating a new subscription or subscriber

Comment: Subscribing to an observer chain that fetches data from a server is the standard way of getting data. If you have an upper limit on the number of fetches you can do, then you will have to manage this somehow, irrespective of using RxJava. Otherwise, if each fetch goes through to completion, then any resources used by the subscription will be freed on completion.

Answer (score 0):

Usual practice - `Single` for server request, instead of `Observable`
If you want to use just a single object - you can do something like:

```
var networkDisposable: Disposable? = null
fun doRequest() {
    networkDisposable?.dispose()
    networkDisposable = yourNetworkRequest().subscribe()
}
```